# Angular Material How To Make A Cell Clickable

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material-5

I am dynamically rendering a material angular table, and i'd like to make a row of cell (rendered via names) clickable.  I don't want to add a button, just make the name that's rendered clickable.

For example, I have a if check (*ngIf="arr.data === 'id'") then render an icon next to the id such as image below.

[image]

I am rendering the eclipse via the if check next to the id 54. How can I make the the id clickable w/o rendering an icon inside angular material table?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="account.accountCode">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Code </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <a href="" [routerLink]="['/accounts', row.account.accountKey]"> {{row.account.accountCode}} </a>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This adds an anchor tag within the cell that you can click on. In this sample, `routerLink` is used for navigation.

Of course, you will want to change the names, and route information.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't wrap the whole cell, only the {{row.account.accountCode}}

Comment: @ILovePHP Wow. Not sure that is a good reason to down-vote, but whatever. The OP does say *just make the name that's rendered clickable* after all.

Comment: it seems like i read too quickly and downvoted without reading what OP asked. I will undo the downvote. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!